# How to enumerate MFC controls if I only have a h_wnd?

Tags: mfc, controls

Long time reader, first time poster.

I'm a big noob when it comes to win32 gui apps so here's my question.

Let's say you have a handle to a window:

```
HWND h_wnd;
```

That window ultimately has a bunch of controls, list, buttons and whatnot.

Now I believe all controls inherit from CWnd (maybe that's not the right technical term in MFC...not sure).  So would I be able to drill down to the controls using something like:

```
EnumChildWindows();
```

Again, I only have access to the top window handle.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC controls are normal windows so you can use `EnumChildWindows`.
`EnumChildWindows` recursively enumerates all child windows of a parent window.